# How can I make a custom sort to be updated automatically when update a cell value in Excel?

Tags: excel, sorting

I have 2 sheets in Excel. First one is the Group Stage standings of Champions League 2019-2020 and the second one is the schedule of Group Stage. I have a connection between them, so when I input the result of one match in the Sheet 2, Teams in the Sheet 1 are rewarded (3 points etc...) My problem is that I can't sort teams by their Points from Largest to Smallest. Actually I can make custom sort but I have to do it every time when I update a final score in the Sheet 2. Is there any way to make this automatically so that the team with the most points be in the first row every time when a score be inserted?

Comment: Afraid this would require an Excel VBA macro bud

Comment: You can use function to get sorted data automatically. So when you put any recent data then it will automatically show sorted data.

Comment: @Harun24HR what kind of function?

Comment: @Apantazo Please check my answer and let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below formula as per screenshot.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$7,ROW($A1)),$B$2:$B$7,0)),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]